# Is there any difference in German between a Faserlaser and a Farblaser?

Tags: meaning, difference, technical-terminology, scientific-language

G'day.

Sorry to interrupt with a pretty simple question but, while [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faserlaser) and many, many Chinese suppliers discuss fib(er|re) las(er|re)s using the word ***Faserlaser***, many high-end German suppliers themselves seem to prefer the word ***Farblaser*** for similar products. Wiktionary has no entries on [any](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fiber_laser) [of](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Faserlaser) [them](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Farblaser). Are they complete synonyms that can be used interchangeably? or is there a nuance I'm not picking up on?

Comment: At least some suppliers are using Farblaser to talk about fiber lasers (like the question already explained) but apparently it's the less common general term and might be misleading. Thanks.

Comment: Any particular reason to downvote the question? Are you guys trying to drive people away? or what was the issue here?

That people dropped by like haxor and didn't read the question, where I specifically _linked_ to the Wikipedia page he suggests that I look at?

Comment: @Ily I would like to make you aware of our Code of Conduct (https://german.stackexchange.com/conduct), in particular of the part saying _No subtle put-downs or unfriendly language._ I can understand that sometimes a downvote is frustrating. But please make sure to always keep a friendly tone. Votes don't need to and should not be justified. We have to accept them as they are, even if we don't like or understand them. Please don't take this personal.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Again, none of that is new and reread my post. I didn't take anything personally. I asked for clarification of a confusing point and accurately described Haxor's failure to read the question, without even getting into the condescension involved. Since you're repeating it, though, yeah, stop.

Comment: @Ily I am not repeating anyone's point and I am not taking a position in the argument. My remark was about tone, not about content or argumentative validity.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Then you should police yours more carefully. It's incredibly condescending and unwelcoming in this exchange, the moreso since its premises are so misguided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A **Farblaser** (colloquial for **Farblaserdrucker**) is a colour laser printer, a **Faserlaser** is a fibre-coupled laser (used in research labs for example).

Comment: For the former the full word is *Farblaserdrucker* (I consider the truncation as colloquial), and it is mentioned on the [Wiktionary page for Laserdrucker](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Laserdrucker) and marked as a not yet existing page.

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned that, I'll edit the answer accordingly!